# How is the new "project Treble" going to android make update easier?

Tags: updates, ota-update

https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/05/google-hopes-to-fix-android-updates-no-really-with-project-treble/

It might seem very idiotic on my part not to try to google this but this seems interesting and I am in a new territory here. How are Silicon manufacture and device maker customizing android dessert release and board support package respectively? .What is Phone SKU?